# VBA - Loop through and copy/paste value on range based on different cell value

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have been struggling with this code.  I want to loop through Column E beginning with E5, on the Sheet titled "pivot of proposal" (which is a pivot table); and every time it finds a cell with the value of "check" I want it to copy/paste value of cells A & B of the corresponding row to the sheet titled Check Payments in E & F, moving down a row each time but beginning on row 4.  I tried to piece together other bits of code but it is not doing what I need it to.

```
Sub Loop_Check_Payments()


 Dim c As Range
    Dim IRow As Long, lastrow As Long, krow as long
    Dim copyrow As Integer
        Dim rSource As Range
    Dim DataOrigin As Worksheet, DataDest As Worksheet, DataDestACH As Worksheet
    

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Sheet Where "L" needs to be checked
    Set DataOrigin = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot of proposal")
    '~~> Output sheet
    Set DataDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHECK PAYMENTS")
    Set DataDestACH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ACH_WIRE PAYMENTS CASH POOLER")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   
        '~~> Set you input range
        Set rSource = Range("Payment_Method")
        

        '~~> Search for the cell which has "L" and then copy it across to sheet1
        For Each c In rSource
            If c.Value = "Check" Then
            
                        
            DataDest.Cells(4 + IRow, 5) = DataOrigin.Cells(c.Row, 1)
            DataDest.Cells(4 + IRow, 6) = DataOrigin.Cells(c.Row, 2)
            IRow = IRow + 1
                        
              Else
              DataDestACH.Cells(4 + kRow, 7) = DataOrigin.Cells(c.Row, 1)
            DataDestACH.Cells(4 + kRow, 8) = DataOrigin.Cells(c.Row, 2)
                kRow = kRow + 1
                      
               End If
        Next c
           
            
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
   
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are pasting, you have to copy something first.

Comment: If you're only copy/pasting values, then a copy/paste is not necessary. Simply `DataDest.Cells(4 + IRow, 5).Value = c.Value` will do it.

Comment: PeterT - I think that is close, however I need it to get the values in a diff column of the same row as c.value.  So if  it finds "check" in E6, I want to copy/paste B6:c6 to another worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to Copy/paste - you can do something like this (as PeterT alluded to in comments)

this will put values from columns A&B (ordinal 1 & 2) of the SOURCE to the same row/column in the destination:

```
    If c.Value = "Check" Then
        DataDest.Cells(c.Row, 1) = DataOrigin.Cells(c.Row, 1)
        DataDest.Cells(c.Row, 2) = DataOrigin.Cells(c.Row, 2)
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified the code in my original post, but it is still not putting the data beginning in Row 4 based on the code I have. I need it to start in Row 4 of the Dest and move down sequentially so there are no blank rows

Comment: I fixed it.  I had to dim another variable as krow to maintain the row for the second group. Duh! Thanks for the help